# Bind Events to UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can i propagate the PreviewKeyDown event out from the myUserControl which is inside a myWindow.

in myWindow.xaml

```
<local:MyFilter x:Name="check" MyEvent="submit" />
```

in myUserContorl.xaml

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="combo" PreviewKeyDown="{Binding Path=MyEvent}" />
```

in myUserContorl.xaml.cs

```
#region MyEvent

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Label which is displayed next to the field
    /// </summary>
    public EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        get { return (EventHandler)GetValue(EventHandlerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EventHandlerProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identified the Label dependency property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EventHandlerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyEvent", typeof(EventHandler),
          typeof(myUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    #endregion
```

This works for just 'string fields' like content or text... but doesn't work for events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add (and remove) event handlers to the underlying control:

```
public event KeyEventHandler MyEvent
{
    add { combo.AddHandler(PreviewKeyDownEvent, value); }
    remove { combo.RemoveHandler(PreviewKeyDownEvent, value); }
}
```

without any Binding in XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combo" />
```

Comment: Thanx. But, 
How can i pass MyEvent from myWindow   

`<local:myWindow x:Name="check" MyEvent="submit" />`

`private void submit(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
           ....
        }
`

Comment: As you already have it, but change RoutedEventHandler to KeyEventHandler.